# How do packets flow when I have a ELB, and NAT gateway in a public subnet that distributes traffic to three of my nodes in my private subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

I was wondering if someone could answer the question for me?

My understanding right now is:

1. Client makes request and packets first hit the route table for the public subnet
2. Route table routes the packets to the ELB
3. ELB routes packets to NAT Gateway
4. NAT Gateway routes packets to route table for private subnet
5. Private route table routes packets to one of the three nodes

Is this correct? Also are there any resources to understand the packet flow?

Comment: Your understanding seems to be quite inconsistent with what actually happens, but to give you a good and accurate explanation, please clarify: Which type of ELB -- Classic, Application, or Network?  Where is the client -- on the Internet?

Comment: Currently I'm using a Classic ELB that resides in the public subnet, also the client is on the internet making a HTTP request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some notable problems with your description.

Classic ELBs do not route packets.

They work at either layer 4 (TCP mode) or layer 7 (HTTP mode) and in both cases they copy payload from one TCP connection (browser to ELB) to another TCP connection (ELB to instance) and back.  This is why the instance sees the IP address of the balancer rather than the IP address of the browser.  IP packets are below layer 4.

NAT Gateways are not used at all in handling ELB traffic.

NAT Gateways are for outbound connections, which means connections originated inside your VPC to destinations outside.  This does not include reply traffic from the ELB.  Without a NAT Gateway, the traffic through the ELB works the same as always, but the instances on the private subnet have no way of establishing outbound connections -- to talk to third party APIs, to set their clock to external time servers, to download software updates, or to communicate with any AWS service that doesn't have a VPC endpoint configured, such as S3, DynamoDB, etc.

The route tables are mostly irrelevant, because the only route that is actually used is the default route on the public subnet(s) where the ELB itself is located.  This route allows the reply traffic to return from the ELB to the external client via the Internet Gateway.  Everything else uses the implicit local routing that is built into VPC and not configurable -- traffic inbound from the client is implicltly routed to the ELB, and traffic between ELB and the instances is implicitly routed in both directions as well, because the source and destination IP addresses are internal private addresses of the ELB and the instances.  The ELB and the instances communicate directly, not using any gateway device (such as a NAT Gateway).

For each connection needed, the ELB specifically selects one healthy instance and creates a connection to it.  When the balancer is in TCP mode, there is a 1:1 relationship between client connections and instance connections.  When the balancer is in HTTP mode, there are typically fewer instance connections than client connections, because the ELB will only establish as many connections to the instances as are needed based on traffic, and client connections tend to spend a significant amount of time doing nothing, between page loads.